# how does .AttachAll() work for updating and inserting

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

This question is pretty simple , but  I can't seem to get a clear answer from MSDN docs.

I have a list of objects that map to a table in my database.  Some of these objects have the `ID` filled out, some don't.  I want to use something like

```
myContext.myTable.AttachAll(myList);
```

now , I was hoping that the objects that have an ID - which is Primary Key in the database will get attached and perform an update to those rows,  and my objects that don't have an `ID` will be treated like an INSERT , and the db will automatically create an `ID`.  Is that how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534401%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This method attaches all entities of a collection to the DataContext
>   in either a modified or unmodified state. If attaching as modified,
>   the entity must either declare a version member or must not
>   participate in update conflict checking. If attaching as unmodified,
>   the entity is assumed to represent the original value. After calling
>   this method, the entity's fields can be modified with other
>   information from the client before SubmitChanges is called. For more
>   information, see Data Retrieval and CUD Operations in N-Tier
>   Applications (LINQ to SQL).
>
> When a new entity is attached, deferred loaders for any child
>   collections (for example, EntitySet collections of entities from
>   associated tables) are initialized. When SubmitChanges is called,
>   members of the child collections are put into an Unmodified state. To
>   update members of a child collection, you must explicitly call Attach
>   and specify that entity.

Comment: still not 100% clear , i use .AttachAll(myList, false)

Comment: The Table class has the AttachAll method. All affected entities are attached and are waiting for insert/update command. You can specify a subentity (myList) to narrow the set to be attached.